# Отсылаются сообщения одному и тому же пользователю aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

При написании телеграм бота у меня появилась проблема. Когда после запуска бота нажимаешь на "Настройки" с одного аккаунта он отлично работает, но когда пишешь со второго, то сообщение отправляется первому пользователю, а не второму и то же самое с третьим, всё приходит первому пользователю.
Проверял через print(message.chat.id), от какого id приходит сообщения, пишет правильный id, но отправляет всё равно первому.
Заранее спасибо!

Вот часть кода, с которой у меня проблема:

```
    if message.text == "Настройки":
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здесь вы можете настроить свой аккаунт', reply_markup=keyboard_settings(id))
    @dp.callback_query_handler(text="serv")
    async def sub(call: types.CallbackQuery):
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите сервис', reply_markup=keyboard_serv())
        @dp.callback_query_handler(text="wth")
        async def sub(call: types.CallbackQuery):
            con = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur = con.execute(f'SELECT id FROM subs WHERE id={message.chat.id}')
            check = cur.fetchall()
            print(check)
            if not str(message.from_user.id) in str(check):
                con.execute(f'INSERT INTO subs(id) VALUES ({message.from_user.id})')
                con.commit()
            con.close()
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хотите подписаться на рассылку погоды?', reply_markup=keyboard_danet())
            @dp.callback_query_handler(text="yes")
            async def sub(call: types.CallbackQuery):
                class wth(StatesGroup):
                    wtht = State()
                    wthtz = State()
                    wthtown = State()
                await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Во сколько отправить вам информацию о погоде?\nНапример: 7:00")
                await wth.wtht.set()
                @dp.message_handler(state=wth.wtht)
                async def ans_qq1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
                    answer = message.text
                    await state.update_data(answerwtht=answer)
                    data = await state.get_data()
                    answerwtht1 = data.get("answerwtht")
                    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Какой у вас часовой пояс?\nНапример: если UTC:+1, то +1")
                    await wth.wthtz.set()
                    @dp.message_handler(state=wth.wthtz)
                    async def ans_qq2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
                        answer = message.text
                        await state.update_data(answerwthtz=answer)
                        data2 = await state.get_data()
                        answerwthtz1 = data2.get("answerwthtz")
                        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "О каком городе хотите получать информацию?")
                        await wth.wthtown.set()
                        @dp.message_handler(state=wth.wthtown)
                        async def ans_qq3(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
                            con = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
                            cur = con.cursor()
                            answer = message.text
                            await state.update_data(answerwthtown=answer)
                            data = await state.get_data()
                            answerwthtown1 = data.get("answerwthtown")
                            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы успешно подписались на рассылку")
                            await bot.send_message(5036976963, f"{message.from_user.id} Подписался на рассылку(Погода)")
                            con.execute(f'UPDATE subs set wthsub = "yes" WHERE id={message.from_user.id}')
                            con.execute(f'UPDATE subs set (wthtimee, wthtimezone) = ("{answerwtht1}", "{answerwthtz1}") WHERE id={message.from_user.id}')
                            con.execute(f'UPDATE subs set wthtown = "{answerwthtown1}" WHERE id={message.from_user.id}')
                            con.commit()
                            await state.finish()
                            con.close()
            @dp.callback_query_handler(text="net")
            async def sub(call: types.CallbackQuery):
                await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Подписка на рассылку успешно отменена", reply_markup=keyboard_menu())
```

Также вот "клавиатуры":

```
def keyboard_menu():
keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton('Погода', one_time_keyboard=True))
keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton('Настройки'), types.KeyboardButton('Тех. поддержка☎️', one_time_keyboard=True))
return keyboard

def keyboard_danet():
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
danet = {'Да':'yes', 'Нет': 'net'}
for zxc in danet:
    keyboard.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(zxc, callback_data=danet[zxc]))
return keyboard

def keyboard_settings(id):
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
settings = {'Сервисы': 'serv', 'Язык': 'lang', 'Рассылка': 'spam'}

for zxc in settings:
    keyboard.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(zxc, callback_data=settings[zxc]))

return keyboard

def keyboard_serv():
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
serv = {'Погода': 'wth'}
for zxc in serv:
  keyboard.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(zxc, callback_data=serv[zxc]))
return keyboard
```

И если нужны таблицы:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INTEGER,
    username TEXT,
    lang TEXT DEFAULT('ru'),
    balance REAL DEFAULT(0)
    )''')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subs (
    id INTEGER,
    wthsub TEXT DEFAULT('no'),
    wthtimee TEXT,
    wthtimezone TEXT,
    wthtown TEXT
    )''')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spam (
    txt TEXT
    )
    ''')
con.close()
```

А вот [тут](https://github.com/Julie3Sigtuna/searchbot) полный код

Comment: Господи, что я за страшный код только что увидел? Почему у вас хендлер внутри хендлера? Черт возьми у вас получилась матрёшка из нескольких хендлеров! И вы хотите чтобы у вас все работало правильно? Пожалуйста сделайте хендлеры нормально. Отдельно друг от друга. И уберите эти чёртовы ифы. Сделайте нормальный хендлер с фильтром текста и все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

почему у Вас хендлеры в методе?

попробуйте вместо message.chat.id вписать call.chat.id на [166 строке](https://github.com/Julie3Sigtuna/searchbot/blob/4100f8a1aaf555ad3d0f907f719c00e347873178/main.py#L163)

Comment: Спасибо большое!